# Linking with glog library

Tags: c++, glog

I'm trying to use the glog logging library ([LINK](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/)).
In VS2012 (I'm on Windows 8 Professional 64-bit (Japanese)), I create an empty solution with a single main.cpp file like the one in the documentation ([LINK](http://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html)).
Also I import the glog project inside the solution (either the dll one or the static library one) and set the project dependency.
To avoid some errors I have to comment out line 97 from port.h:

```
/* In windows-land, hash<> is called hash_compare<> (from xhash.h) */
#define hash  hash_compare
```

While glog compiles, the main application gives me unresolved external symbol erros (with both dll and static version).

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "void __cdecl google::InitGoogleLogging(char const *)" (?InitGoogleLogging@google@@YAXPBD@Z) が関数 _main で参照されました。
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "public: __thiscall google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const *,int)" (??0LogMessage@google@@QAE@PBDH@Z) が関数 _main で参照されました。
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "public: __thiscall google::LogMessage::~LogMessage(void)" (??1LogMessage@google@@QAE@XZ) が関数 _main で参照されました。
```

I'm compiling as Win32.
If I check the debug folder it actually contains the dll+lib or static lib file.
I also tried linking to the library manually without using the visual studio dependency system, but it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built glog for MSVS2012 from trunk (little patch mentioned in header already presented here, as i know), so it works for me.
Looks like your dependency description of glog library is missing.

Can you add windows-specific

```
#pragma comment(lib, "path_to_glog_from_project_dir.lib")
```

to one of your project files, for example, directly into main.cpp and test it.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't have the project so can't try, but I'm pretty sure I was linking correctly to the library. Probably building glog from the source is a good idea anyway!

Comment: I added glog as a separate project and recompiled, it worked.